# How to synchronously download files from URL in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to download a number of files from Flickr using Flickr APIs and `http.get()` calls in a loop.

I have the array of image URL's and I use 'download' function to download pictures 
If there is a big number of images there are mostly empty files.
I found the download code here.
Please advice how to approach this.
Thanks in advance!

```
for (i=1;i<100;i++){

    filename= "./images/file"+i+".jpg";

    download(photourl[i], filename,{});


    } //End of for-loop 

.....

var download = function(url, dest, cb) {
  var file = fs.createWriteStream(dest);
  var request = http.get(url, function(response) {
    response.pipe(file);
    file.on('finish', function() {
      file.close();
      //cb();
    });
  });
}
```

P.S. And then finally there is error:
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: socket hang up
    at createHangUpError (http.js:1442:15)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd [as onend] (http.js:1538:23)
    at Socket.g (events.js:175:14)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:910:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)

Comment: I strongly suggest not doing this synchronously, even if you are able to figure out how to do that.  I would recommend creating queue of files to download, and running that queue as images are downloaded one-by-one, or as many as you want at a time.  Throttling is important, as you have noticed.

Comment: Brad, thanks! How do I start with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend to use async module for this:

```
var i = 1, threads = 5;
require('async').eachLimit(photourl, threads, function(url, next){
  download(url, "./images/file"+(i++)+".jpg", next);
}, function(){
   console.log('finished');
})
```

and uncomment cb(); in the download function

Comment: maybe `eachLimit` would be a better choice rather than trying to download **all** of the images simultaneously?

Comment: may be, and may be not) I change it, thanks.